# Chrome dev tools reports “Stalled' and ”Initial connection" under mobile mode only

Tags: page-speed, http-headers, google-pagespeed

[image]

One of my static pages(generated by Hugo) is loading slow on mobile mode, but the exact same page was fine on desktop mode. (google page load speed desktop score 97, but failed Core Web Vitals on mobile)

On the chrome-devtools desktop mode, the stalled time was only 2.6 ms, but on mobile mode was 458.74ms. There was no initial and SSL connection time on desktop mode, mobile mode 458.61ms initial time, 233.98ms SSL.

Any idea how to fix it?
My server is CentOS 7 64GB RAM, Apache 2.4 event module, 1GB Memcached, mod_pagespeed, + tmpfs.

```
<IfModule mpm_event_module>
StartServers            30
MinSpareThreads         100
MaxSpareThreads        400
ThreadsPerChild        64
MaxRequestWorkers      256
MaxConnectionsPerChild   0
</IfModule>
```

[image]

Comment: When you are testing mobile, do you have any connection speed throttling enabled like in this screenshot?  https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/device-mode/imgs/throttling.png

Comment: No throttling, just default "online".

Comment: If you repeat the desktop and mobile tests each several times, are the results consistent?